# How do I embed a userform into an Excel sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

When my Excel spreadsheet is opened I want the userform to open in the top left corner of sheet 1. I don't want the userform to be able to be moved or closed. Is this possible?

Comment: Userforms are generally modal or non-modal windows that sit "above" your Excel application. What you're talking about is certainly possible if you place the form controls (buttons, text fields, combo boxes, etc) directly on the spreadsheet. The controls will pretty much stay where you put them (with the caveat that zoom levels and sheet scrolling could affect how they're displayed). If you fill all cells with a shade of gray and draw cell boundaries with the same shade of gray, the worksheet will look like a userform background.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your UserForm code pane:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.StartUpPosition = 3 'set starting position a the top-left of your window
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Layout()        
    With Me
        .Left = 0 ' set left position to the window left margin           
        .Top = 0  ' set top position to the window top margin
    End With    
End Sub
```